# What does function "eventloop" do in Scala Actors?

Tags: scala, actor

What does function `eventloop` do in Scala [Actors](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.actors.Actor%24) and what is it useful for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`eventloop` works similarly to `loop` and `react` being combined. The difference between `loop` and `eventloop` is that `loop`, in fact, doesn't call the body recursively (to prevent stack overflow for thread-based actors), but schedules handling (react/receive) of a next message from the mailbox, and finishes execution of a current handler throwing an exception, to clear up the call stack.

`eventloop` recursively handles the messages using `react` - in case of `react` it's safe (and stack doesn't get overflown), because the body of `react` (but not `receive`!) always ends with an exception, in the most cases, and the next loop scheduled, to guarantee a fair access to the thread pool form all actors. Therefore, `eventloop` can be used only with event-driven actors.

```
import scala.actors._
import Actor._

class EventLoop extends Actor {
   def act = eventloop{
      case msg => println("Received " + msg)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [this thread](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Channels-and-Actors-td1993006.html) can give some details:

> One important motivation for actors is that they allow you 
>   to avoid control inversion meaning that there is at most one thread 
>   executing inside an actor at a time, and the user chooses when this is 
>   going to happen by writing a straight-line program that waits for 
>   messages at explicit points in the control flow.
>
> In this model, one usually wants to avoid passing callback functions out to other threads that invoke them asynchronously; instead, other threads should interact with an actor only by sending messages to it. **If callback-like behavior is wanted then the following pattern achieves it 
>   in a thread-safe manner**:

```
  def eventloop() { 
    react { 
      case Event1 => 
        // handle Event1 
        eventloop() 
      ... 
      case Eventn => 
        // handle Eventn 
        eventloop() 
    } }
```

> This pattern is provided as an abstract operation in [`Actor.eventloop`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/actors/scala/actors/Actor.scala#L257):

```
  import scala.actors.Actor._ 

  eventloop { 
    case Event1 => 
      // handle Event1 
    case Eventn => 
      // handle Eventn 
  }
```

> Note that there is no need for tail calls to some enclosing function any more.

---

That being said, considering the thread dates from 2008, and the [Scala Actor API guide](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/actors-api/actors_api_guide.html#) doesn't mention `eventloop` once, maybe this not used that often.
[Vasil Remeniuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354067/vasil-remeniuk) expertly details `eventloop` usage in [his answer (+1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317053/what-does-function-eventloop-in-scala-actors/6317978#6317978) and gives a concrete example in the question "[Client-Server example with Scala actors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317142/client-server-example-with-scala-actors)".