# Client-Server example with Scala actors

Tags: scala, actor

What is the best way to implement the following example ?

- Actor `server` receives `Requests`,
  handles them, creates a new `Response`
  for each `Request` and sends the `Response` back
  to the `Request` sender.
- Actor `client` sends `Requests` and
  receives `Responses`.

All this communication is asynchronous and hence it uses `react`.

This is just an example and so it should not handle all those cases like `server` is down, `client` is stuck, etc. It should be just concise and expressive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import scala.actors._
import Actor._

case class SendRequest(rid: String)
case class Request(rid: String)
case class Response(rid: String)

val server = actor {
   eventloop {
         case Request(rid) => 
            println("Server got request [%s] from client" format(rid))
        sender ! Response(rid)  
      }
   }   
}

val client = actor {
   eventloop {
         case SendRequest(rid) => server ! Request(rid)
         case Response(rid) => 
            println("Client got response [%s] from server" format(rid))
      }
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> client ! SendRequest("Hello!")
Server got request [Hello!] from client
Client got response [Hello!] from server
```

With regards to:

> All this communication is asynchronous
>   and hence it uses react.

Actors that use `receive` are also asynchronous. They just block the thread, waiting for a new messages.